# get apple's icons from device or simulator

Tags: ios, icons, ios-simulator

I want to make an app that completely adheres to Apple's most recent design.
Therefore, I want to 'borrow' some icons.
Of course I could make a screen shot, but since I don't own an iPhone X, chances are, that I only would get the @2x resolution.
Since the simulator runs fine on my Mac, I'm sure I should be able to find the resources to native iOS apps somewhere on my hard drive.
Question: where?

Comment: Possible [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you want to 'borrow' these icons? They're proprietary, and you'll be unable to submit an application that uses them. According to Apple: "*You are granted no right or license with respect to any of the aforesaid trademarks and any use of such trademarks.*"

Comment: @ Obsidian Age: While that doesn't answer my question, maybe we could have an offline discussion on this? Apple also has the right to reject an app when it has a poor UI. At the same time, many UI elements are forced upon you by the SDK. I guess there is a huge grey area between theft and flattery

Comment: want you @2x resolution screenshot?